# Saving an integer array to a file in C

Tags: c, fwrite

I've been trying to write the contents of an integer array to a file in C. I've been using the code below to do so.

```
int etData [600];
int i;
int size = sizeof(char);

for (i=0; i<600; i++)
{
  etData[i] = analog_et(5);
}
    
FILE *f = fopen("/home/root/Documents/KISS/Default User/Launch Code/data/data", "w");

fwrite(etData, size, sizeof(etData), f);

fclose(f);
```

analog_et is a function that returns an integer value from a sensor. Whenever I run this code, a mess of ASCII characters is written to the file. I believe this is to blame on the fact that I am passing fwrite an element size sizeof(char) - however, whenever I attempt to pass a value larger than one byte, nothing is written to the file, and fwrite fails to return a non-zero value.

I've looked for a function in stdio that would be better suited to this purpose but can't find one. Any suggestions on how to fix this issue? Thanks!

Comment: you probably want to open the file in binary mode

Comment: It's not "a mess of ASCII".  It is raw data, some of which is printable and looks like a mess when you try to view it as if it is ascii.  View the data with a hex dump tool like `xxd`.

Comment: Side note: don't use twice `600` but `#define DATA_SIZE 600` and then use `DATA_SIZE` instead of `600`.

Comment: `size_t fwrite(const void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream);` where `size` of `1` with `sizeof(etData)` is equivalent to `size` of `sizeof(int)` and `nmemb` being `600`. The only different is in your case `fwrite` returns the number of **bytes** written and in the second case it would return the number of **elements** (`int`) written. `fwrite()` writes output in **binary**, not ASCII. (the funny ASCII you see is your editor trying to interpret the binary file) See @Jabberwocky answer for alternative.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a textual representation of your data (in that case the file can be opened with a text editor), you cannot user `fwrite` but you need to use `fprintf`. Latter does basically is the same thing as `printf`, but instead of being displayed, the data is written into a text file.

You probably want this:

```
...
FILE *f = fopen("/home/root/Documents/KISS/Default User/Launch Code/data/data", "w");

for (i=0; i<600; i++)
{
  fprintf("%d\n", etData[i]);
}
...
```